# Print text between two patterns if a match if found

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with multiple repeating patterns.
I want to print the relevant information if a match is found in between each matching pattern.

For example:

```
START PATTERN1 pat1
START PATTERN2 pat2
text1 0
text2 2
text3 8
text4 10
STOP PATTERN2 pat2
STOP PATTERN1 pat1
START PATTERN1 pat3
START PATTERN2 pat4
text1 0
text2 2
text3 10
text4 10
STOP PATTERN2 pat4
STOP PATTERN1 pat3
```

I want to start my search from `START PATTERN1`
and if I find that `text3 8` exists
I need to print out both `pat1` and `pat2` as indicators of where this occurred.

So I could use either the start before this match or the stop after this match.

But otherwise I don't want do do anything.

so from the above file I would run the command and the output would be:
pat1
pat2

Since that is the only section that contains "text3 8" within.
Any help?

Comment: Your patterns nest like this and you need to keep the full set of matching patterns that come before the line you are matching on?

Comment: So you will see this same pattern repeat many times in the file.
But I only need to print the info if "text3 8" exists.  
If "text3 2" exists - I don't care.

Comment: That didn't answer my question. Do the patterns nest as in your example or do they just repeat? Do you need a single start pattern or all the start patterns you see (presumably that don't match stop patterns) before the matching line you are looking for?

Comment: To explain even further... this is a configuration output.  So I need to find which objects have a configuration parameter set.  Problem is searching between two patterns - but outputting information conditionally with a match between those two patterns.

Comment: You really need to answer my question and/or give us actual representative output.

Comment: Q: "Do you have a dog?" A: "Dogs have tails". Funny how people THINK they're answering a question when they're really only answering it in their head ... ;-).

Comment: I thought I did answer the question.  They are not nested.  See the altered example already provided.  They repeat - but are not nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you expect ?

```
awk '
    $0 ~ "START PATTERN1"{l=1}
    l==1 && $0 ~ /^text3 8$/{l++}
    l==2 && $1 == "STOP"{print $NF}
' file
```

And from your comments, only print it if text3 is anything BUT 8 :

```
$ awk '
    $0 ~ "START PATTERN1"{l=1}
    l==1 && $0 ~ /^text3 [^8]$/{l++}
    l==2 && $1 == "STOP"{print $NF}
' file
```

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -00lne '
  foreach $count (1..2) {
  print $1 if
  /START\s+PATTERN${count}.*^text3\s+8\s*\n.*?STOP\s+PATTERN${count}\s+(\w+)/ms}
' file
```

Comment: `l>1`, more than one match and the third pattern won't trigger. But I'm also not sure this does what they want though it might.

Comment: Ok.  The relevant info can be pulled before or after since it exists in both places.  I'll try to update the original text with a better example of the data and the expected output.

Comment: Seems to fit the specs ?!

Comment: Actually - I think it does. 

One more wrench - what if I want to only print it if text3 is anything BUT 8?  Is that doable?

Comment: Sputnick - you are awesome...

Ok - I have one more question.
There are other items I can report on.  
How do you reverse search from the "text3" point?

Comment: The latest added perl'one should fit better your needs, take a look